# PayPal IPN losing session on return?

Tags: php, session, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using Micha's PayPal IPN script and for the most part it worked great: https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN

When i click Pay now on the website it redirects to paypal with correct information, allows payment to be made, but on return nothing happens, ie it does not upgrade the user as it should. Now i've tested the script my code outside of the IPN and it works perfect so it looks to me like the IPN script is losing the session?

Here is my button code:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="EMAIL_TO">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Text Light">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.01">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://domain.co.uk/editors">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://domain.co.uk/account/upgrade">
    <input type="submit" value="Pay now" class="btn btn-preview" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

So the notify url (IPN code) is /account/upgrade -- as far as i know this is where it should perform the upgrade task? so here is my (stripped down) code

```
if ($verified) {

    $errmsg = '';

    // some error checking

    if (!empty($errmsg)) {

        // manually investigate errors from the fraud checking

    } else {

        // upgrade user
        $package = serialize($_SESSION['package']);
        $this->db->update('users',array('id' => $_SESSION['user']['id']),array('payment_plan' => $package));

    }

} else {

    // not verified, investigate problems
}
```

As above, the code under '// upgrade user' works fine outside, but on return from paypal it's obviously not keeping hold of the session. It's not throwing any errors, it's just not doing anything.

Where have i gone wrong? how can i ensure that session information will be passed back from PayPal.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has a short answer: IPN isn't done as the user.

To expand on the answer, here's how IPN works. You make a payment, your visitor returns to your site, and **PayPal** pings your IPN URL. The important bit is in bold - the request will come from PayPal and not from the user, and will therefore not inherit the user's session!

The reason for this is pretty simple - the IPN URL is supposed to be private, as you could do all sort of silly shenanigans if it wasn't (including creating virtual transactions). For this very reason, the user never sees this address. (Another reason is that not all browsers will follow redirects - and IPN is designed to provide information 100% of the time).

If you would like to do this, you'll need to pass a parameter to the IPN request indicating who the user is. Passing the user ID is a *very* bad idea - as parameters as modifiable. Instead, generate a transaction ID of some sort containing the info on the user, and pass this. On the IPN call, you'll get this variable back as a custom parameter, which will allow you to fetch stuff from your DB and do whatever you want, knowing who the user was.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, isn't the IPN url always visible because of the notify_url hidden field?

Comment: If you're overriding the IPN call with this, make sure you double-check with PayPal that the transaction exists... as the IPN data format is pretty well-known and someone might very well have some fun with it. The rest still applies, though - a PayPal server pings this, not your user.

Comment: Thanks, does this seem like a valid solution:
Ok so i know the problem, paypal doesn't know what the session is, so it can't apply the changes on return

solution:

on the payment processing page (right before the buyer clicks to head over to paypal) the details of their 'package' should be stored in a database, along with the user id, and session id.. we could give this a status as 'unconfirmed'?

we send the session id to paypal along with the payment information, on return we catch the session ID and query it in the database, it pulls the information and we can apply it to the user?

Comment: This is the way to go - though you should rely on IPN and confirmation with paypal (through CURL) to do so.

Pass the session ID as an extra field - you get three in total, if memory serves me right. Alternatively, pass an order ID and store the contents of the order on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I saw an answer posted elsewhere that worked for me.  For the return_url, I simply removed the "www" part of my web address.  So, instead of the retun_url being "https://www.mywebsite.com/ReturnPage.aspx" I changed it to "https://mywebsite.com/ReturnPage.aspx".  This seems to keep the session intact.